# MVC 5 DropDownList lookup text

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ViewBag there is object that contains Id,First name and Last name. I want to display DropDownList that has Id as value and "First name"+" "+"Last Name" as text.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.person, "Id","Last Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This is the line of code that I use currently, how can I modify it to display the right info?

Comment: simple why cant you do concatenation and send list to view bag in text & value format later you use `new SelectList(ViewBag.list, "text","value")` . use list<selectedlistitem> store inside . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your controller and model to send the concatenated text to the View, or create a new `SelectList` in the View itself that concatenates the values before passing it to the `DropdownListFor`.

What you are trying to achieve would be possible if `SelectList` had an overload with a callback for formatting, but this isn't possible.